# Отслеживание JavaScript опросника с помощью Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

На сайте используется онлайн-опросник, написанный на javascript. Используется просто вставкой соответствующего кода на странице. Можно ли с помощью Google Alalytics отследить, дошел ли пользователь до последнего вопроса или нет? Первым, что пришло в голову это повесить событие OnClick, но потом вспомнил, что как такового виждета с опросником нет, есть js-код, который отвечает за его отображение и работу.

Comment: Если есть JS код, отвечающий за работу опроса, то почему нельзя вставить в этот код обработчик события `click`?

Comment: @Regent, в том-то и дело, что нет исходника. Я использую уже готовый код виджета-опросника, т.е. я знаю только, например: <script src="site.com/widget.js"></script>

Comment: Но в _widget.js_ ведь не скомпилированный код - можно взять его и посмотреть. Разве что он может быть минифицированным. В противном случае остаётся только писать дополнительный скрипт, который будет следить за `click` или изменениями в DOM.